# Stop grunt-ts from compiling references

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, typescript, grunt-ts

I've recently switched from using Web Essentials to grunt-ts to compile my typescript files due to the flexibility of output. Part of the reason I switched is that I don't want all files compiled seperately, and I don't want to have all files compiled to a single file. I want a bit of both. Since I've recently started using grunt for a lot of tasks, I thought I might as well switch my TS build too.

Here's my gruntfile

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        dirs: {
            distribution: 'script/dist',
            ts_root: 'script/src',
            ts_controllers: 'script/src/controllers'
        },
        ts: {
            apprunner: {
                src: ['<%= dirs.ts_root %>/main.ts'],
                out: '<%= dirs.distribution %>/src/main.js',
                options: {
                    target: 'es5'
                }
            },
            controllers: {
                src: ['<%= dirs.ts_controllers %>/*.ts'],
                out: '<%= dirs.distribution %>/src/controllers.js'
                options: {
                    target: 'es5'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['ts']);
};
```

Inside the `main.ts` file, I have to reference one of the typescript files that, when compiled, makes up part of the `controllers.js` file.

So my `main.js` file I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="controllers/ExampleController.ts" />

var newExample = new wctApp.controllers.ExampleController();
```

Grunt compiles my `controllers.js` file fine:

```
var wctApp;
(function (wctApp) {
    (function (controllers) {
        var ExampleController = (function () {
            function ExampleController() {
            }
            return ExampleController;
        })();
        controllers.ExampleController = ExampleController;
    })(wctApp.controllers || (wctApp.controllers = {}));
    var controllers = wctApp.controllers;
})(wctApp || (wctApp = {}));
```

But it compiles the same code inside the `main.js` file.

```
var wctApp;
(function (wctApp) {
    (function (controllers) {
        var ExampleController = (function () {
            function ExampleController() {
            }
            return ExampleController;
         })();
        controllers.ExampleController = ExampleController;
    })(wctApp.controllers || (wctApp.controllers = {}));
    var controllers = wctApp.controllers;
})(wctApp || (wctApp = {}));
;
var newExample = new wctApp.controllers.ExampleController();
```

If I remove the reference from the main file, it won't build because it can't find ExampleController. How can I keep the reference to this file, but stop it from being compiled in the `main.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `out`. Because `out` merges all the TypeScript files into one. Instead use `outDir` (if you need to redirect to a different folder). Or better don't use *anything* (no `out` no `outDir`) and it will put the generated JS next to the file.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, and works. Just out of curiosity, would there be a way to specify a different compiled file name using the outDir method? Or will it always be the same as the source JS file?

Comment: @JamesHay it will always be the same